# Structuring a reducer for a simple CRUD application in redux

Tags: redux

So I'm creating what is at it's core a very simple CRUD-style application, using React + Redux. There is a collection of (lets call them) posts, with an API, and I want to be able to list those and then when the user clicks on one, go into a detail page about that post.

So I have a posts reducer. Originally I started using the approach taken from the redux real-world example. This maintains a cache of objects via an index reducer, and when you do a "get post" it checks the cache and if it's there, it returns that, else it makes the appropriate API call. When components mount they try to get things from this cache, and if they're not there they wait (return false) until they are.

Whilst this worked OK, for various reasons I now need to make this non-caching i.e. everytime I load the /posts/:postId page I need to get the post via the API.

I realise in the non-redux world you would just do a fetch() in the componentDidMount, and then setState() on that. But I want the posts stored in a reducer as other parts of the app may call actions that modify those posts (say for example a websocket or just a complex redux-connected component).

One approach I've seen people use is an "active" item in their reducer, like this example: https://github.com/rajaraodv/react-redux-blog/blob/master/public/src/reducers/reducer_posts.js

Whilst this is OK, it necessitates that each component that loads the active post must have a componentWillUnmount action to reset the active post (see resetMe: https://github.com/rajaraodv/react-redux-blog/blob/master/public/src/containers/PostDetailsContainer.js). If it did not reset the active post, it will be left hanging around for when the next post is displayed (it will probably flash for a short time whilst the API call is made, but it's still not nice). Generally forcing every page that wants to look at a post to do a resetMe() in a componentWillUnmount fells like a bad-smell.

So does anyone have any ideas or seen a good example of this? It seems such a simple case, I'm a bit surprised I can't find any material on it.

Comment: What do you mean by "If it did not reset the active post"? Could you provide a real use case?

Answer (score 0):

How to do it depends on your already existing reducers, but i'll just make a new one

**`reducers/post.js`**

```
import { GET_ALL_POSTS } from './../actions/posts';

export default (state = {
  posts: []
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ALL_POSTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { posts: action.posts });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

It is very easy to understand, just fire an action to get all your posts and replace your previous posts with the new ones in the reducer.

Use `componentDidMount` to fire the `GET_ALL_POSTS` action, and use a boolean flag in the state to know if the posts where loaded or not, so you don't reload them every single time, only when the component mounts.

**`components/posts.jsx`**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Posts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      firstLoad: false
    };
  }

  componendDidMount() {
    if (!this.state.firstLoad) {
        this.props.onGetAll();
        this.setState({
            firstLoad: true
        });
    }
  }

  // See how easy it is to refresh the lists of posts
  refresh() {
    this.props.onGetAll();
  }

  render () {
    ...

    // Render your posts here
    { this.props.posts.map( ... ) }
    ...
  }
}
```

We're just missing the container to pass the posts and the events to the component

**`containers/posts.js`**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getPosts } from './../actions/posts';
import Posts from './../components/posts.jsx';

export default connect(
  state => ({ posts: state.posts }),
  dispatch => ({ onGetAll: () => dispatch(getPosts()) })
);
```

This is a very simple pattern and I've used it on many applications

Answer (score 0):

If you use react-router you can take advantage of onEnter hook.